# Life on board ship was not (such as/as?) I had expected it to be

Tags: phrase-usage, prepositional-phrases

> Life on board ship was not (such as/as?) I had expected it to be.

Which is better from *as* and *such as* to use in the above sentence ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance using `as` on its own would flow much better.

This is also a very formal way of saying this sentence and would probably feel odd if used in conversation.

Comment: It is a slightly formal way of making the statement,  and is how I would expect to see it written.  I wouldn't find it odd if used in conversation though.  An alternative option in a more conversational tone is: 'Life aboard ship wasn't what I expected.'

Comment: I'd expect to see it written that way too. Your alternative is closer to what I think of when phrasing it conversationally.